# Dell XPS 15 95606, Dell Dock TB16, Dell 2414H

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, dell, 17.04, thunderbolt

I just bought a [Dell XPS 15 95606](http://www.dell.com/de/p/xps-15-9560-laptop/pd?oc=cnx95606&model_id=xps-15-9560-laptop) and installed Ubuntu 17.04 on it. It works perfectly fine and I am very satisfied. Based on the review within this [article](https://vetruvet.blogspot.de/2017/02/linux-on-xps-15-95509560-with-tb16-dock.html) I also bought a [Dell Thunderbolt Dock TB16](http://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/dedhs1/sln301105/dell-thunderbolt-dock--tb16--information--specifications--frequently-asked-questions?lang=en) in order to connect my laptop to my two [Dell 2414H](https://www.amazon.de/Dell-U2414H-LED-Monitor-Reaktionszeit-h%C3%B6henverstellbar/dp/B00H3JIGHA/) monitors.

So, my setup currently looks like this:

```
                                |---- mDP ----> Dell U2414H
XPS 15 ---- TB/USB-C ----> TB16 |---- ... ----> USB, Ethernet, ..
                                |---- DP  ----> Dell U2414H
```

However, everytime I have more than one external screen connected to the dock, one or both of the external screens start to flicker. The flickering does not match any pattern but happens randomly, sometimes it is only one screen, sometimes both are flickering. I also checked the cables and they do not seem to be broken, as there is no flickering when using a different laptop. The laptop's screen is turned off while connected to the dock, because two monitors are enough.

As I am relatively new to the linux world, I started to google whether anyone has the same problem as I do. However, I could not find anything similiar and decided to ask here for some help.

More information:

- Ethernet, USB, etc. all these ports work on the dock, as I already
  turned off the security measure for thunderbolt devices within the
  BIOS.
- Before installing Ubuntu I also updated the BIOS with drivers
  from Dell within Windows.

Comment: I'm curious if you've made in progress on this one month old question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Unfortunately I didn't make any progress on the problem. Instead I switched one display to HDMI. The HDMI-screen never flickers, but the DP-screen flickers sometimes. When it occurs, I just unplug the screen and plug it in afterwards again. If you make any progress, I'd be glad if you could share it.